# What is the highest two-man stat line from teammates in NBA history?

Tags: basketball, statistics, history, nba

For example, during the 2012-2013 NBA Season, Kevin Durant averaged 28.1/4.6/7.9 and Russell Westbrook averaged 23.2/7.4/5.2.

Does anyone know what the best two person line has been in history? Or how I might go about finding out myself?

Comment: You can always comb through http://www.basketball-reference.com/ and see if something catches your eye.

Comment: @New-To-IT how would you comb through basketball-reference.com in order to find two teammates with the highest points/assists/rebounds on a given team, then compare that among seasons? http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/583

Comment: @New-To-IT see meta post...we're currently discussing these types of questions.

Comment: I think this would need to be programmatically checked on a database, the manual checking would be too much. I figured something like that would be the answer, I assume stats inc for example has database engineers on staff to write queries to find information like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the early 2000s Lakers with Shaq and Kobe. They were both putting up close to 30 per game for a season or 2.

Try the 00-01' and 01-02' seasons. 02-03' is possible even though Shaq had a tough year compared to usual. That was the year Kobe had the 12 consecutive 40 point games.

Your question could be taken to mean a few different things though. Highest combined PPG, highest points and assists average, points and rebounds, highest total statistical output. Which in using each of those, it could change the answers alot.  You could look at Moses Malone and Dr. J from about 82' to 86', Jordan and Pippen in the 6 90s seasons they were both on the court for Chicago, Shaq and Kobe like i said, Duncan and Robinson from 97' to 00' or so, Jabbar and Magic in the early 80s, Jabbar and Adrian Dantley in the late 70s,  likely enough Wilt with Jerry West and/or Elgin Baylor in the late 60s/early 70s. Lebron and D-wade from 10' to 14' i bet too. To do this go to BasketballReference, go down to Team Stats for the given year and you can see it all as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Stephon Marbury and Steve Francis put up like 75 shots a game while playing together with the Knicks.

[image]